# Do you know a good open source message queue with a REST interface?

Tags: rest, open-source, message-queue

I have a need for an open source message queue that has a REST interface. I have tried ActiveMQ, but [this bug](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/204-No-Content-after-sending-message-to-queue-with-active-consumer-td4255617.html) makes it unsuitable. I have also tried HornetQ, but [this bug](http://community.jboss.org/thread/176357?tstart=0) makes that unsuitable.

Does anyone have real world working experience with an open source REST based message queue?

Comment: http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Message_Queue_Evaluation_Notes is a good resource, even if it doesn't detail the availability of REST interfaces.

Comment: Pick the one of those two you like, fix the bug, then bingo! :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) with [a REST interface](http://code.google.com/p/amqp-rest/).